# Recover deleted text in a saved .txt file on windows 7

Tags: windows, notepad

So my problem is with a text document(.txt) which I've been using for months, editing and saving stuff, once I accidentally deleted some of the text and saved it. I'm very interested if there's a way to recover the text I've deleted from the document and how would I do it on windows 7

Comment: Yes I did click save changes after i accidentally deleted the text.
If it helps, before that accident I've saved the file with the information that I've accidentally deleted and saved after. So  Can I recover it?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/miufa5 looks like I've not enabled the backup, so it's lost then? Thanks Anyway I'll enable it now for future

Comment: You might file the file from the before the update in the Recycle Bin.

Answer (score 1):

In a way you can. A software like 'Active@ Undelete' can do it. Once you Scan the desired HDD, you go to your file, RMB > 'Inspect File Record'. There you can find the deleted text. It's important you do this as soon as you notice the mistake. You can see there are already some errors in the part "This is the text that will be deleted before file is saved."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some backup programs installed, it's not possible to recover the deleted text.

Comment: This should be a comment.